Hydration Error in Next.js with Countdown Timer and Client-Side Dynamic Content
I'm encountering a "hydration failed" error in my Next.js app when trying to display a countdown timer. The error message states:
"Hydration failed because the server rendered HTML didn't match the client."
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import ProfilPic from "../../asset/IMG_1878.jpg";

function calculateTimeLeft() {
  // Some calculation logic for the countdown
}

export default function Rsvp() {
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(calculateTimeLeft());

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeLeft(calculateTimeLeft());
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Countdown Timer */}
      <div className="mt-6 text-xl font-semibold">
        <p className="text-lg">Wedding Countdown</p>
        <div className="flex justify-center space-x-4 mt-4">
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
            <span className="text-2xl">{timeLeft.days}</span>
            <span className="text-sm">Days</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
            <span className="text-2xl">{timeLeft.hours}</span>
            <span className="text-sm">Hours</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
            <span className="text-2xl">{timeLeft.minutes}</span>
            <span className="text-sm">Minutes</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
            <span className="text-2xl">{timeLeft.seconds}</span>
            <span className="text-sm">Seconds</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

Problem:
When the page loads, it renders fine on the server, but once React hydrates on the client side, I get the following error:
Hydration failed because the server rendered HTML didn't match the client.
